Unable to access index for repository, can't install packages
I installed R and Rstudio but having problems to install any package.  My PC is a Windows 10.
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/fvarelaa/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  no fue posible abrir la URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4:
  no fue posible abrir la URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/PACKAGES'


I tried to install and looked an lots of blogs and videos but can't manage.

Try a different mirror.

In particular, try https://cran.rstudio.com (using https, not http).
